# How many ways are there to express an infinite number of primes? (like $4k+1$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For example, you can express infinitely many primes as $4k\pm1$ and as $6k\pm1$.

Would it be true that for any integer n, we can find an integer k such that there exists at least one prime of the form $nk\pm1$? (just guessing)

How many "formulas" like these exist? Is there a pattern?

(I am asking out of curiosity, but also one of the reasons to ask is that some proofs/problem solutions use a certain way to express a prime for proving a certain property and I wander if there are some rules/regularities on the use of primes of different forms.)

Comment: Dirichlets theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions covers this, and says to this problem "yes, such a $k$ always exists."

Comment: You can also change "at least one prime" to "infinitely many primes", for any $n$.

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions says that if $n$ and $b$ are positive, and $\gcd(n,b)=1$, then there are infinitely many primes of the form $nk+b$. Note that $nk-1$ can also be expressed as $n(k-1)+(n-1)$, so you can always write them in the form $nk+b$ with $b\gt 0$, except perhaps for one such prime.

Comment: In one variable , the arithmetic progressions $ak+b$ with coprime positive integers $a,b$ are the only known examples. Examples like $k^2+1$ are not known to produce infinite many primes , although this is highly conjectured. It is known that there are infinite many primes of the form $a^2+b^4$ , where $a,b$ are positive integers.